# Checking the returned value from POST by Curl

Tags: c#, php, web-services, curl

I'm calling a remote C# WebService using curl.The service returns 0 or 1 depending on the values passed to it by checking a database. When I use `echo $result` the value is printed correctly. But when I try to compare the output value, the code does not work. Please advise

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ( $result == 0 )
{
     echo("Valid");
}
else
{
     echo("Invalid");
}
```

VarDump is --->string(103) " 0"

**UPDATE**:

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

**UPDATE2**:
C# Webservice Code
(return type is int)

```
  try { if (dr.HasRows) { c.Close(); return 0; } else { c.Close(); return 1; } }
```

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: @Nick `string(103) " 0"`

Comment: @techno then it should be `intval(trim($result)) === 0`.

Comment: @vivek_23 This prints valid every time,even when the result is `string(103) " 1"`

Comment: @techno That's not possible looking at my condition. What results do you expect for `1` and `0`? Please add these in your post.

Comment: @techno perhaps there's some non-printable characters in the response. What if you try `$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $result);`?

Comment: @Nick Its printing `invalid` always..

Comment: @Nick The response is provided by a C# webmethod 
            `try
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    c.Close();
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    c.Close();
                    return 1;
                }
            }`

Comment: @techno that doesn't seem to agree with the result of `var_dump` being a 103 character string...

Comment: @Nick Please see the update.printing the result directly gives the correct value though.

Comment: @techno yes, but non-numeric characters at the beginning of a string will cause PHP to interpret it as 0 in a numeric context, hence `Valid` always being displayed. See this for example:https://3v4l.org/AFU5p

Comment: @Nick How can i solve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you change `try { if (dr.HasRows) { c.Close(); return 0; } else { c.Close(); return 1; } }` to `try { if (dr.HasRows) { c.Close(); return '0'; } else { c.Close(); return '1'; } }`

Comment: @Nick The current method return type is `int` i will have to change it to `string`

Comment: @Nick That also does not solve the issue.

Comment: What happens if you `print_r(array_map('ord', str_split($result)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are actually getting an XML return from the curl request. The actual text of the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<int xmlns="http://www.example.com/">1</int>
```

You are not seeing the XML because you are printing into an HTML environment and those tags are being swallowed (`echo htmlspecialchars($result);` would have made it obvious). You will need to parse the XML e.g. using

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$result = (int)$xml;
```

and then you can use the result value.